# lost_pass=1 URL of my crawled but unindexed product pages on GSC

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, google-search-console, hashbang

I'm really hoping someone can help me.
My website https://www.bathroomfusion.co.za is built with WordPress and I use Ecwid to manage the products for the website.

I did a site search to see what appears in the SERP `site:https://bathroomfusion.co.za` and there are 421 results, I see that there are all my pages created with WordPress and a handful of products that link to other products or categories, e.g.

- **8511 Double Robe Hook** - Store
  `https://www.bathroomfusion.co.za/store/?_escaped_fragment_=%2F8511-Double-Robe-Hook%2Fp%2F537697611&lost_pass=1#!/Bath/c/145682036`
- **Moderna Double Basin** - Store `https://www.bathroomfusion.co.za/store/?_escaped_fragment_=%2FModerna-Double-Basin%2Fp%2F562051822&lost_pass=1#!/8502-Paper-Holder-II/p/537697335/category=145853967`

I'm not sure why only some products are listed or why their URLs are merged together with `lost_pass=1`

Im assuming I need to share my .htaccess file, so here's the mess :

````
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.13.1
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since weâre sending far-future expires, we donât need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "WP Rocket/3.13.1"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/avif                                  avif
    AddType image/avif-sequence                         avifs
</IfModule>
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest           "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 1 hour"
    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                  "access plus 1 week"
    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif-sequence           "access plus 4 months"
    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component              "access plus 1 month"
    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Donât compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/html .html_gzip
AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_.+|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/community/(.*)/|/participant/(.*)/|/sign-up/(.*)/|/sign-in/(.*)/|/change-password/(.*)/|/ftg/|/(?:.+/)?feed(?:/(?:.+/?)?)?$|/(?:.+/)?embed/|/(index\.php/)?(.*)wp\-json(/.*|$))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END WP Rocket

# BEGIN YOAST REDIRECTS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 "/f-a-q" "/billing-order-information"
Redirect 301 "/product-promotion/warm-towels" "/product-promotion/warm-towels-heated-towel-rail"
Redirect 301 "/25years-of-dado-quartz" "/elementor-landing-page-4118"
Redirect 301 "/elementor-landing-page-4118" "/25years-of-dadoquartz"
Redirect 301 "/knowledge-base-2/dadoquartz/spec-sheet" "/knowledge-base-2/dadoquartz/spec-sheets"
Redirect 301 "/elementor-landing-page-4441" "/thank-you"
Redirect 301 "/elementor-landing-page-4309" "/hansgrohe-special-splash-less-cash"
Redirect 301 "/category/promotions" "/category/general"
</IfModule>
# END YOAST REDIRECTS

# BEGIN Ecwid
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN Ecwid" and "END Ecwid" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
# END Ecwid

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
Order deny,allow
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.php
# BEGIN SMUSH-WEBP
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN SMUSH-WEBP" and "END SMUSH-WEBP" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/smush-webp/disable_smush_webp !-f
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/smush-webp/$1.webp -f
 RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.*\.(?:png|jpe?g))$ wp-content/smush-webp/$1.webp [NC,T=image/webp]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header append Vary Accept env=WEBP_image
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
# END SMUSH-WEBP```
````

my robots.txt file in case its needed:

```
# START YOAST BLOCK
# ---------------------------
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?s=
Disallow: /page/*/?s=
Disallow: /search/

Sitemap: https://www.bathroomfusion.co.za/sitemap_index.xml
# ---------------------------
# END YOAST BLOCK
```

**Your help is so very appreciated**

I havent tried anything yet

Comment: The example URLs you have given use the "escaped fragment" syntax, a thing that in the early days of AJAX was used to make such pages crawlable. That syntax is deprecated, https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/332 - but the meta tag mentioned there, `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` can still be found in the source of your product pages - so I guess, Google itself is coming up with those URLs, based on that meta tag. My advice: Figure out what inserts that into your pages, and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an unexpected meta tag `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` on my product pages. After narrowing down that the Ecwid plugin was inserting the meta tag, I discovered that the option 'ecwid_seo_links_enabled' within Ecwid's hidden parameter settings was disabled, causing the tag. Enabling it resolved the problem.

Option that I needed to enable: `ecwid_seo_links_enabled: on`

[image: options]